# Where do i find the staticresources?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Where do i find the staticresources defined? I have a textbox that has the following style:

```
Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for PhoneTextTitle1Style in your solution?

Comment: no reason to downvote. It's a reasonable question

Comment: @Dave S - that wouldn't be in his solution - it's in the standard platform resources instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some lists online - e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

If you want to see the Xaml, then take a look in your wp7 sdk directory - e.g. In c:/program files x86/Microsoft sdks/windowsphone/7.1/design - you'll find theme resource Xaml files in there which define all the platform common styles for each colour scheme (dark and light)

Answer (score 3):

This page has a list of current styles for windows phone 7.1 and 8:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx